# How to configure nginx to not show the log in console?

Tags: nginx, logging, vue.js, console, console.log

I have a web application in production (with Vuejs), and use nginx as a proxy. I would like to not show the log in the browser console. I try it:

```
  server {   

  listen 80 default_server;   
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  access_log  /dev/null;   
  error_log /dev/null;

  access_log  off;   
  error_log off;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  index index.html;

  server_name you.server.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;   }

  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;   }

  location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";   }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you'd like to archive. What kind of log you'd like to get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

**Nginx can't control output to browsers console!**

Simply delete console logs from your code.

*FYI*: If you'd like to

- remove "You are using development version of Vue" in browser console you can make it by [running Vue in production mode](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html)
- [disable vue devtools inspections](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#devtools) add this code

```js
  // make sure to set this synchronously immediately after loading Vue
  Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

- [suppress all Vue logs and warnings.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#silent) add this code

```js
  // make sure to set this synchronously immediately after loading Vue
  Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

Comment: Not work! Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.silent = true; added in main.js